90s movie about teen who will invent time travel and is visited by old future self
I remember seeing this in the early 2000s, there is this teenager who is both smart and a good athlete so he's been accepted to both scientific and athletic universities. For the moment he hasn't decided where to go. He's neglecting the physical exercises because he thinks he could be on the brink of inventing time travel. He has a blackboard at his place where he tries different formulas. He lives in a pretty large house in an area which looked rural.
Somehow he comes across an old man who looks like actor David Hemblen in La Femme Nikita as George. He is old, has white / gray hair without visible balding, looks very much like this actor but with a happier face, not always frowning (https://xmentascom.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/hemblen-2.jpg) and a bit fat. The old man tells him he is from the future. They spend a lot of time together, the old man teaches him a thing or two but somehow cannot or will not give him the missing formulas our hero needs to finish his time traveling machine.
At some point either the old man slips this or the teen figures out from some idiosyncratic behavior that the old man is his future self. At that point he abandons his time travel theories and starts running and doing sit-ups because he thinks no way he's ending up like that old man who's a bit fat and not very fit. He is now decided to follow an athletic career. I think he was exaggerating since the old man was not very chubby. Some chin and belly fat on top of David Hemblen's pic, or like Danny Aiello at the most.
However, his old self manages to convince him to go back to his research because he will discover the X theory / Y effect that will earn him a Nobel prize or a similar level or fame and recognition. I think at this point the old man returned to his timeline and we get a glimpse of the teen discovering the final piece.

Movie or TV Episode?..Sounds a but thin to be a whole movie.

Could be an episode too. I remember seeing it in a morning where TV series were intertwined. But I did look first at the wiki list of episode synopsis for The Outer Limits 1995 series (found episode "To Tell The Truth" for other memories) and Twilight Zone and none matched. Amazing Stories by Steven Spielberg isn't either.

Can't find much on it but All Over Again (2001) AKA Against Time seems to fit the bill, at least partly.





17 year old Z.T., a brilliant mind and solid athlete, dreams of a great college and a future of invention and innovation. But he still grieves over his mother's recent death, a shoulder injury will likely prevent him from an athletic scholarship, and his father has squandered his college trust fund in bad investments. His situation is desperate. 
Suddenly Z.T. is confronted with ZACK, a raving, 67 year old alcoholic, who claims to be Z.T.'s older self, volunteering as a lab rat in the first experiments in time-travel. Zack has changed his identity to fool the scientists, in a desperate attempt to convince his younger self to avoid a terrible compromise in integrity, which will ultimately set him on a downward spiral toward ruin and tragedy. 
Z.T. is understandably skeptical, but ultimately is forced to consider Zack's claims. Together they attempt to provoke the old man's fragile, piece-meal memory, to find the exact moment and small choice that began the domino effect of Z.T.'s compromise in integrity. As they do, a unique bond forms, as Z.T. comes to value his other relationships from a much different perspective... one that considers the quality of man he becomes, fifty years hence.


Ok so I looked this up and it seems that it has an alternate name, Against Time and that also it was released in 2007 in the US. A few searches later and I come up with the trailer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kS_7zuYPTq4
This looks very much it actually. Seeing the characters & reading the synopsis definitely brings back more memories.

Thank you for the effort. I wound up here asking the more difficult movies to find that I remember watching. I thought this might be either an episode of some series I missed or a TV movie. But it was just a more unpopular one it seems.
